# Stringtemplate: is it ok to Apply Templates, in which HashMap uses, To Multi-Valued Attributes

Tags: java, hashmap, stringtemplate

There is two template in my .stg file, and both of them apply on
multi-value a HashMap. The HashMap is employed as an injected object.

And I need those instance of HashMap can be injected for many times.

My trouble is, when I switch to another template, ANTLR seems to
consider the second HashMap as a List -- multipul objects and null
value.

---

```
Part of my .stg file shows as follows:

tpl_hash(BAR, FOO) ::= <<
<FOO:foo(); separator="\n">
<BAR:bar(); separator="\n">
>>

foo(nn) ::= <<
foo: <nn.name; null="NULL"> . <nn.national; null="NULL">
>>


bar(mm) ::= <<
bar: <mm.name> @ <mm.national>
>>
```

---

Part of my .g file shows:

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
hm.put("name", $name.text);
hm.put("national", "German");
tpl_hash.add("FOO",new HashMap(hm));
HashMap hm2 = new HashMap();
hm2.put("name", $name.text);
hm2.put("national", "German");
tpl_hash.add("BAR",new HashMap(hm2));
```

---

The result I expect is :

```
bar: Kant @ German
foo: Russell @ England
```

---

But, I got:

```
foo: NULL . NULL
foo: NULL . NULL
bar:  @ 
bar:  @
```

---

If we replace BAR with FOO, as is, keeping FOO and BAR with identical
template, the output is right, like the following.

```
bar: Russell @ German
bar: Russell @ German
```

---

In docs, "synchronized ST add (String name, Object value) in
org.stringtemplate.v4.ST" said:

"If you send in a List and then inject a single value element, add()
copies original list and adds the new value."

What about a HashMap? Does StringTemplate consider the HashMap, key/value pair
access, an object purposely, as a List and as multi-value injected by
mistake?

Comment: You tagged and mentioned ANTLR, but I don't see a question about ANTLR (only StringTemplate). I therefor removed the ANTLR tag and replaced the mentioning of "ANTLR" with "StringTemplate". If I'm wrong, you can revert back to your original question, but please edit the question to make clear what the ANTLR problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are applying the foo / bar templates to each item in the map rather than to the map itself.

Consider the following data structure:

```
{
  "FOO": {
    "name": "Nick",
    "national":"German"
  },
  "BAR": {
    "name": "Karl",
    "national":"French"
  },
  "FIZZBUZZ": [
    {
      "name": "Kitty",
      "national":"English"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dan",
      "national":"Finnish"
    }
  ]
}
```

(Imagine that you've set FOO to be the resulting map, FIZZBUZZ, etc.).

And imagine the following templates:

```
group blank;
main()::=<<
$foo(nn=FOO)$
$bar(mm=BAR)$

$! This is wrong because it applies foo to each element of the map!$
$FOO:foo(); separator = "\n"$

$! This is right because each element of baz is itself a map! !$
$FIZZBUZZ:foo(); separator = "\n"$
$FIZZBUZZ:bar(); separator = "\n"$
>>

foo(nn) ::= <<
foo: $nn.name; null="NULL"$ . $nn.national; null="NULL"$
>>


bar(mm) ::= <<
bar: $mm.name$ @ $mm.national$
>>
```

You will get the following output:

```
foo: Nick . German
bar: Karl @ French

foo: NULL . NULL
foo: NULL . NULL

foo: Kitty . English
foo: Dan . Finnish
bar: Kitty @ English
bar: Dan @ Finnish
```

So just change your call from `FOO:foo()` to `foo(nn=FOO)`

I used the little StringTemplate app engine project I developed (http://stringtemplate.appspot.com/) to test this; it's not using version 4.0 but 3.2 I think, but it should be very similar.